# how to assign part of a matrix to other matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 30 x 30 matrix, called `A`, and I want to assign `B` as the leftmost 30 x 20 block of A how can I do that?

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
B = A[30 ; 20]
```

Comment: `B = A(:,1:20);` is the correct code, `:` mean "all"

Comment: I would recommend checking out [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) as a starting point.

Comment: And i agree with excaza start by reading the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the correct way is

```
B = A(:, 1:20);
```

where `:` is shorthand for all of the rows in A.

Matrix indexing in MATLAB uses round brackets, `()`. Square brackets, `[]`, are used to declare matrices (or vectors) as in

```
>> v = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
v =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

[excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) provides a very good link on [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?refresh=true) which should help you. There is also [Matrix Indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

`A_new = A(:,1:20)`

takes all the rows from A with this part `A(:,)` and the first 20 columns with this part `A(,1:20)`

`A_new`is now 30x20

You can also iterate over elements in two loops, but the above answer is easiest